# How to replace the missing values with the median for the variable using gsub in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data frame that I extracted from an html file of a Wikipedia page table. I want to replace the missing values with the median of each variable.

From the hints given I know that I need to convert the `factor` type to `numeric` values, and I likely need to use `as.numeric(gsub())`.

```
renew$Hydro[grep('\\s', renew$Hydro)]
as.numeric(gsub('', median(as.numeric(renew$Hydro)), renew$Hydro))
lapply(renew, function(x) as.numeric(gsub('', median(as.numeric(x)), x)))
```

I tried using `grep()` to show that `'\\s'` is the pattern for extracting spaces, but the spaces were actually excluded from the output and only digits were shown.

When I tried using `as.numeric(gsub())`, the output looked like:

```
[1] 5.415405e+13 5.475475e+13 5.475425e+07 5.475415e+13 5.400000e+01 5.400000e+01 5.435405e+16
[8] 5.425435e+13 5.400000e+01 5.415455e+16 5.445425e+16 5.415495e+13 5.400000e+01 5.400000e+01
```

which does not at all resemble the data frame which looks like:

```
[1] 1035.3   7782     72       7109                       30134.8  2351.2            15318
```

I expected the output to look exactly like the original data frame but with the spaces filled in with the column medians.

Edit:
This is what the beginning of the data frame looks like. It's from "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_electricity_production_from_renewable_sources".

```
> renew
                             Country    Hydro     Wind     Bio   Solar
1                        Afghanistan   1035.3      0.1            35.5
2                            Albania     7782                      1.9
3                            Algeria       72     19.4           339.1
4                             Angola     7109              155    18.3
5                           Anguilla                               2.4
6                Antigua and Barbuda                               5.5
7                          Argentina  30134.8    554.1  1820.4    14.5
8                            Armenia   2351.2      1.8             1.2
9                              Aruba             130.3     8.9     9.2
10                         Australia    15318    12199    3722    6209
11                           Austria    42919     5235    4603    1096
12                        Azerbaijan   1959.3     22.8   174.5    35.3
13                           Bahamas                               1.9
14                           Bahrain               1.2             8.3
15                        Bangladesh      946      5.1     7.7   224.3
```

Comment: I'd be happy to help with this if you could provide some example data.

Comment: added head of data frame, hope that helps

Comment: It might be worth going back a few steps and trying to set up your data nicely in the first place. `Country` should be a character/factor, but all the other columns you show should be numeric, so you should see if you can a) read them in as numeric, or b) convert them to numeric right after reading them in. `gsub()` is generally for changing text data, so you will probably have a bad time applying it to numeric data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to note that the data isn't clean yet just after scraping, since `lapply(renew, function(x) grep(",", x))` yields something.

Clean it first with `gsub` to avoid these values being converted to `NA`s when you convert the data to numeric. Here a one step solution, correct `NA`s are created automatically:

```
renew[-1] <- lapply(renew[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",", ".", x))))
```

After that you could run a sapply

```
# sapply(2:5, function(x) renew[[x]][is.na(renew[[x]])] <<- median(renew[[x]], na.rm=TRUE))
```

or of course a shorter adaption of *@Ronak Shah's* second base R code line, which is a lot better:

```
renew[-1] <- sapply(renew[-1], function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), median(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

***Result***

```
summary(renew)
#                      country        hydro                wind                bio              solar        
# Afghanistan        :  1   Min.   :      0.8   Min.   :     0.00   Min.   :    0.2   Min.   :    0.1  
# Albania            :  1   1st Qu.:    907.8   1st Qu.:    50.45   1st Qu.:  151.1   1st Qu.:    4.8  
# Algeria            :  1   Median :   2595.0   Median :   109.00   Median :  242.5   Median :   22.3  
# Angola             :  1   Mean   :  19989.3   Mean   :  4324.13   Mean   : 2136.3   Mean   : 1483.3  
# Anguilla           :  1   3rd Qu.:   7992.4   3rd Qu.:   293.55   3rd Qu.:  344.4   3rd Qu.:  124.5  
# Antigua and Barbuda:  1   Max.   :1193370.0   Max.   :242387.70   Max.   :69017.0   Max.   :67874.1  
# (Other)            :209
```

***Data***

```
library(rvest)
renew <- setNames(html_table(
  read_html(paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries",
                   "_by_electricity_production_from_renewable_sources")),
  fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)[[1]][c(1, 6:9)], c("country", "hydro", "wind", "bio", "solar"))
renew$country <- factor(renew$country)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have empty spaces in your dataframe the columns are turned as characters and there is no meaning in taking `median` of character columns. We can first replace the empty spaces to `NA`, convert the columns to numeric and then `replace` `NA`s with `median` of the column. Using `dplyr` we could do the following steps.

```
library(dplyr)
renew[renew == ""] <- NA

renew %>%
   mutate_at(-1, as.numeric) %>% #-1 is to ignore Country column
   mutate_at(-1, ~ replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE)))


#             Country   Hydro    Wind    Bio  Solar
#1        Afghanistan  1035.3     0.1  174.5   35.5
#2            Albania  7782.0    21.1  174.5    1.9
#3            Algeria    72.0    19.4  174.5  339.1
#4             Angola  7109.0    21.1  155.0   18.3
#5           Anguilla  4730.1    21.1  174.5    2.4
#6  AntiguaandBarbuda  4730.1    21.1  174.5    5.5
#7          Argentina 30134.8   554.1 1820.4   14.5
#8            Armenia  2351.2     1.8  174.5    1.2
#9              Aruba  4730.1   130.3    8.9    9.2
#10         Australia 15318.0 12199.0 3722.0 6209.0
#11           Austria 42919.0  5235.0 4603.0 1096.0
#12        Azerbaijan  1959.3    22.8  174.5   35.3
#13           Bahamas  4730.1    21.1  174.5    1.9
#14           Bahrain  4730.1     1.2  174.5    8.3
#15        Bangladesh   946.0     5.1    7.7  224.3
```

---

We could do the same using base R

```
renew[renew == ""] <- NA
renew[-1] <- lapply(renew[-1], function(x) 
      as.numeric(replace(x, is.na(x), median(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: This seems to work well, but when I run the base R code all of the data frame values change. I get [1]   6.0 143.0 141.0 140.0  81.5  81.5  81.0 rather than [1] 1035.3   7782     72       7109

Comment: @LaurelDaly seems to work for me. Did you apply the base R code on changed `renew` dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in a compact way with `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)
library(zoo)
renew %>%
    retype %>% # change the type of columns
    # replace missing value of numeric columns with median
     mutate_if(is.numeric, na.aggregate, FUN = median)
# A tibble: 15 x 5
#   Country              Hydro    Wind    Bio  Solar
#   <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Afghanistan          1035.     0.1  174.    35.5
# 2 Albania              7782     21.1  174.     1.9
# 3 Algeria                72     19.4  174.   339. 
# 4 Angola               7109     21.1  155     18.3
# 5 Anguilla             4730.    21.1  174.     2.4
# 6 Antigua and Barbuda  4730.    21.1  174.     5.5
# 7 Argentina           30135.   554.  1820.    14.5
# 8 Armenia              2351.     1.8  174.     1.2
# 9 Aruba                4730.   130.     8.9    9.2
#10 Australia           15318  12199   3722   6209  
#11 Austria             42919   5235   4603   1096  
#12 Azerbaijan           1959.    22.8  174.    35.3
#13 Bahamas              4730.    21.1  174.     1.9
#14 Bahrain              4730.     1.2  174.     8.3
#15 Bangladesh            946      5.1    7.7  224.
```

#### data

```
renew <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
"Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh"), Hydro = c("1035.3", "7782", "72", "7109", "", 
"", "30134.8", "2351.2", "", "15318", "42919", "1959.3", "", 
"", "946"), Wind = c("0.1", "", "19.4", "", "", "", "554.1", 
"1.8", "130.3", "12199", "5235", "22.8", "", "1.2", "5.1"), Bio = c("", 
"", "", "155", "", "", "1820.4", "", "8.9", "3722", "4603", "174.5", 
"", "", "7.7"), Solar = c(35.5, 1.9, 339.1, 18.3, 2.4, 5.5, 14.5, 
1.2, 9.2, 6209, 1096, 35.3, 1.9, 8.3, 224.3)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```